# krb-error 30 error code:KRB5KDC_ERR_S_PRINCIPAL_UNKNOWN Server Name(Unknown) HTTP/Null

Tags: kerberos

I have searched many blog posts but could not get any solution.

I have seen many posts with a similar kind of error but in their case Server Name:

HTTP/Domain Name

I was able to get ticket for the user to go to the server.

But I really dont know why I am getting this kind of error with Server Name as null.

The error is

```
KRBError:
     sTime is Tue Oct 20 10:11:30 EDT 2009 1256047890000
     suSec is 548720
     error code is 7
     error Message is Server not found in Kerberos database
     realm is XXX.YYY.COM
     sname is HTTP/null
     msgType is 30
```

My Config files are like below:

**login.config**

```
com.sun.security.jgss.login {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required client=TRUE useTicketCache=true doNotPrompt=false
    debug=true;
};

com.sun.security.jgss.initiate {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required client=TRUE useTicketCache=true 
    debug=true;
};

com.sun.security.jgss.accept {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required client=TRUE useKeyTab=true
      storeKey=true
     doNotPrompt=true
     principal="HTTP/xxx.yyy.zz.com@YYY.ZZ.COM"
     isInitiator=false debug=true;
};
```

**krb5.config**

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = XXX.YYY.COM    udp_preference_limit = 1
    default_tkt_enctypes = des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc des3-cbc-sha1
    default_tgs_enctypes = des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc des3-cbc-sha1
    permitted_enctypes = des-cbc-md5 des-cbc-crc des3-cbc-sha1

[realms]
    YYY.ZZ.COM= {
      admin_server =xxx.yyy.zz.com
      kdc = xxx.yyy.zz.com
     default_domain =  yyy.zz.com
     master_kdc = xxx.yyy.zz.com
      }

[domain_realm]
    .yyy.zz.com= YYY.ZZ.COM       
   yyy.zz.com= YYY.ZZ.COM
```

Could anyone help me with this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This open source project http://spnego.sourceforge.net has some documentation and examples. I think it might be what you need.